# Why ts-node throws the ReferenceError on undefined variables?

Tags: ts-node

Normally, the reference error is being thrown when we are invoking some property from variable with `undefined` value. For example
`foo.substring(1);` will cause the ReferenceError if `foo` has not been defined.

But why ts-node throws the same error because of below one?

```
console.log(__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__);
```

The error message is:

```
console.log(__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__);
            ^
ReferenceError: __IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__ is not defined
```

O'K `__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__` has not been defined. So what? Why the ts-node not output the `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cannot read property of undefined` and `[foo] is not defined` are different. Using *undeclared* variables gets you a `has not been defined`.

A reference to an undeclared variable should *not* give you back `undefined`, because `undefined` is for variables that have been declared but not given a value (or explicitly given the value `undefined`).

Are you declaring `__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__` anywhere? Because Node won't just pick that up from your environment, if that's what you're expecting (that's my assumption based on your variable name). You could do something like `const isDev = !!process.env.__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING__MODE`

And FWIW, this is just a JS thing, not a TypeScript thing; trying to access undeclared variables will always result in an error in strict mode (which is always-on in modules).

Here's an example of code that would produce each of those two different errors:

```js
const exampleOfPropertyError = (foo) => {
  console.log(foo.bar)
}
exampleOfPropertyError()

const exampleOfUndeclaredError = console.log(ljksdflkjsflkjsdf)
```

And an example of how to work with env vars:

```js
const isDevelopmentMode = !!process.env.__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__

console.log(isDevelopmentMode)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Understood about the error cause. "Are you declaring __IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__ anywhere?" - When run the ".ts" file by ts-node - no. The the same "ts" file is been built by Webpack, the `DefinePlugin` replaces this variable with the appropriate value. "You could do something like" - it is not simple to pass the environment variables when using the TyepORM CLI if the file name is not ".env". That is why I am finding the another ways.

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD Ah so if I understand correctly, the issue is in some more real-world code, with TypeORM's config loader, which forces you to choose just one option (ormconfig, .env, or real environment variables). In that case, it seems like you'll need a workaround, like possibly modifying .env in a `pre` hook in your package.json, or some other method for merging the two. If the issue is with the actual code in your question, you could do something like `const isDev = typeof process !== 'undefined' ? process.env.__IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__ : false`

Comment: O'K, thank you. Your answer is including the explanations, so I'll accept and upvote your answer.